# play framework Form.form cannot find symbol

Tags: java, playframework

I am going through the Play Framework tutorial. I am getting this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol

In /Users/hseritt/devel/todolist/app/controllers/Application.java at line 12.

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class); // ERROR IS HIGHLIGHTED AS Form.form 

public static Result index() {
    return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
}
```

My full code for Application.java:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import models.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class);

public static Result index() {
        return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
}

public static Result tasks() {
    return ok(
        views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
    );
}

public static Result newTask() {
     return TODO;
}

public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
    return TODO;
}
}
```

I am wondering if I missed something in the tutorial or put something in the wrong place.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it helps or perhaps you already tried, but when getting 'strange' errors always try `play clean` first...

Comment: Weird. I had to do this:

    import play.data.Form.*;
    import play.data.Form;

and then change the Form declaration to:

    static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);

Comment: Thanks adis, I should have mentioned that I did try a 'clean' first but great point :-)

Comment: What version of Play are you using?

Comment: Strange, as of version 2.1 the correct syntax should be `Form.form(Task.class);`

Comment: @adis I am facing the same problem on version 2.6.x, did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should import the following:

```
import static play.data.Form.*;
```

Comment: Looks like I've got 2.0.7. I suppose this needs an upgrade. Thanks much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As per jnoob, just change import to `import play.data.Form`, then do `static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);`, worked for me.